# How to Change echo Error Query to redirect 404.php?

Tags: php, mysql

When i test this code , It's show

```
Error Query [SELECT * FROM table WHERE xxxxxx != '1' order by id xxxxxx ]
```

Yes, It's correct

But i want to change from error text to redirect to 404.php

how can i do ?

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE xxxxx != '1' order by id xxxxxx";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
if(!$objQuery){
    header('Location: 404_page.php');
}
```